# Is there a better way to change background image

Tags: gwt

I have 2 images that I want to swap between based on a button click

```
private Image widget1 = new Image("images/AU-wp5.jpg");
private Image widget2 = new Image("images/GB-wp1.jpg");
private boolean flag = false;

private void onClick()
{
    flag = !flag;
    if(flag)
    {                       
        RootPanel.get("stockList").add(widget1);
        RootPanel.get("stockList").remove(widget2);
    }
    else
    {           
        RootPanel.get("stockList").add(widget2);
        RootPanel.get("stockList").remove(widget1);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to swap between images?  I have read about having one Image and changing it's url but can't get that way to work,  only this way.

Comment: Did you try widget1.setUrl("images/GB-wp1.jpg")?

Comment: I had tried it before as that was what I read from the documentation. Working now so must have been a typo.  Can I assume usinig a simgle image is less memory intensive.  What about performance? I don't notice any lag swapping the images about but then my phone is a Quad core

Comment: The performance is limited by (1) the Internet connection, and (2) your browser. There is nothing you can do about it in your code.

Comment: About internet connection ClientBundle usage means only one HTTP request for two images. Right ?

Comment: I am using the generated GWT output for a PhoneGap app.  All images used will be in a local folder to the device and the app will not require an internet connection. Have it working now and looks like I'm good to go.  Thnx for help.  Andrei gave me the correct answer but how do I accept a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SSR mentioned, you can do it via cell resource or you can opt for an easier and recommended approach using CSS.

```
Button button = new Button ( "Click me" );
private boolean flag = true;
button.addClickHandler ( new ClickHandler() 
{
     public void OnClick()
     {
             b.setStyleName( "my-button-clicked-" + flag );
             flag = !flag;
     }
}
```

Your CSS may look like this

```
.my-button-clicked-true{
 background : url ( // image path )
}

.my-button-clicked-false{
 background : url ( // image path )
}
```

Comment: This looks like a neat way of doing this although I have little or no CSS experience it looks like something I should be getting into if I want to push on with my GWT app

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the images are fixed then you should be looking at using Dev Guided Client Bundle feature of GWT to ensure best Optimization and Performance. Relevant Section https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#ImageResource.

Best example of its use is in Tree Nodes + and - symbol toggle.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/search?q=CellTree&origq=CellTree&btnG=Search+Trunk

```
  public interface BasicResources extends Resources {

    @ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
    ImageResource cellTreeClosedItem();

    @ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
    @Source("cellTreeLoadingBasic.gif")
    ImageResource cellTreeLoading();

    @ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
    ImageResource cellTreeOpenItem();

    /**
     * The styles used in this widget.
     */
    @Source(BasicStyle.DEFAULT_CSS)
    BasicStyle cellTreeStyle();
  }
```

Comment: I would only recommend Client Bundle for small images (icons) or images that a user will certainly use (i.e. part of UI, default background, etc.) If an image is large and/or most users may not need it, it's better to use a static image.

Comment: Yes. I am assuming the two images in above example as being Up and Down arrow to indicate price is up or down!!!!!!

Comment: I assumed that author has a British flag and another one is Australian :)

Comment: @SSR: I have mentioned the easy way out :D